# UIRefreshControl automatically calling cellForRowAtIndexPath before the action assigned to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `UIRefreshControl` in my `TableView`. Whenever user drags from top to refresh, immediately `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called before the action assigned to it. How can I avoid this?

I tried removing the action to `UIRefreshControl` but no use same `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called automatically.

`UIRefreshControl` code

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(RefreshControlMethod)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[table addSubview:refreshControl];
```

Comment: Please add the UIRefreshControl initialize code.

Comment: @nandy It is not `UIRefreshControl` that calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` getting called because your TableCell will scroll when you are trying to refersh your `tableView` and it is default behaviour  of tableView that you can't changed it.

Comment: Hooo thanks @NiravD got it.

Comment: @nandy Welcome mate :)